# Strategies for storing frequency of dynamic data

Tags: python, database, algorithm

Sorry if the title is misleading.

I am trying to write a program that calculates frequency of emails being sent out of different email ids. We need to trigger alerts based on number and frequency of mails sent. For example for a particular email if in past 60 minutes more than 25 mails were sent, a trigger needs to be sent.

A different trigger for another directory based on another rule. Fundamental rules are about how many mails sent over past 60 minutes, 180 minutes, 12 hours and 24 hours. How do we come up with a strategy to calculate frequency and store it without too much of system/cpu/database overheads.

The actual application is a legacy CRM system. We have no access to the Mail Server to hack something inside the Postfix or MTA. Moreover there are multiple domains involved, so any suggestion to do something on the mail server may not help.

We have ofcourse access to every attempt to send a mail, and can look at recording them. My challenge is on a large campaign database writes would be frequent, and doing some real time number crunching resource intensive. I would like to avoid that and come up with an optimal solution

Language would be Python, because CRM is also written using the same.

Comment: I think you should try to look at the logs generated at time when any email is sent. This should contain `to` and `from` fields for you to record and is also almost realtime.

Comment: @shivams, as I mentioned no access to any logs or servers

Answer (score 0):

Try to do hack on client side in recording email attempt to a log file. Then you can read that file to count frequency of emails sent.

I think that you can put data in memory in dict for some time say for ex 5 or 10 min. Then you can send data to DB thus not putting load on DB of frequent writes. If you put a check in your code for sudden surge in email from a particular domain then it might provide you a solution for your problem.

Comment: I am already using Redis which is the fastest among free and light in-memory databases. I have already done what you have suggested, but as rules get more complex I feel better granular and more flexible solution is required

Answer (score 0):

Let m be the largest threshold (maximum number of emails sent) of any of your tests.  E.g., if you have a limit of 150 emails per 24 hours, then m = 150 (presumably the thresholds for shorter-period checks are all lower than this -- it wouldn't make sense to also have a limit of 200 emails per 12 hours).  Your longest period is 24 hours, which means m can't be more than 25*24 = 600 -- since if it were, then some checks would be redundant with the 25-emails-per-hour limit.

Since this is quite a small number of emails per user, I'd suggest just keeping a per-user [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) that simply stores the dates and times of the last m <= 600 messages sent by that user.  Every time the user sends a new email, check the send time of the 25th-most-recent message sent; if it's less than 1 hour ago, sound the alarm.  Likewise check the other limits (e.g. if there is also a limit of 50 emails per 180 minutes, check that the 50th-most-recent message was sent more than 180 minutes ago).  If all tests pass, then (over)write the next entry in the ring buffer with the current date/time.  A date/time can be stored in 4 bytes, so this is at most about 2.4Kb bytes per user, with O(1) queries and updates.  (Of course you could use a DB instead, but a ring buffer is trivial to implement in-memory, and the total size needed is probably small enough if you don't have millions of users.)